# Creating subpages

Tags: html

I am pretty new to developing and was hoping you all could help me out with a little issue.

I am currently building a website and have an FAQ page.

for example, the url is www.sitename.com/faq.html

I want to create an FAQ sub page to hold the answers

for example the url would be www.sitename.com/faq/answers.html

my issue is that I have no idea how to create a page as an extension of another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "sub page".  However, if you want to create the answers at the URL *www.sitename.com/faq/answers.html*, you:

- Create a sub-directory called `faq`
- Put answers.html in that sub-directory.

Personally I would instead create a sub-directory called `faq` and put `questions.html` and `answers.html` in that sub-directory.

The URL's would be

www.sitename.com/faq/questions.html

www.sitename.com/faq/answers.html

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to make a folder in the directory that you have faq.html, named faq.